# where(:sku => 'sku123') vs where ('sku =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a strange situation. Here is my model:

```
UpcCode
```

> => UpcCode(id: integer, Upc: string, Sku: string, Active: boolean,
>   created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

As you can see, Sku is one of my columns.

When I type in IRC:

```
UpcCode.where(:Sku => 'SKU123').first
```

I get expected result:

> UpcCode Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "upc_codes".* FROM "upc_codes" WHERE
>   "upc_codes"."Sku" = $1  ORDER BY "upc_codes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
>   [["Sku", "GC-115-42"]]  => #`<UpcCode id: 95, Upc: "70163098XXXX", Sku:
>   "SKU123", Active: true, created_at: "2016-05-11 03:12:11",
>   updated_at: "2016-05-11 03:12:11">`

But when I try this using the following syntax:

```
UpcCode.where("Sku = 'SKU123'").first
```

or

```
UpcCode.where('Sku = "GC-115-42"').first
```

I am getting the following error as if the Sku column does not exist.

> UpcCode Load (5.2ms)  SELECT  "upc_codes".* FROM "upc_codes" WHERE
>   (Sku = "GC-115-42")  ORDER BY "upc_codes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
>   "sku" does not exist

I need to be able to use the second syntax because I need to manipulate the results. i.e. case insensitive comparison.

Comment: All identifiers that are not in double-quote are converted to lower case in PG there for your column name `Sku` get converted to `sku` so it gives this issue you can use as `UpcCode.where('"Sku" = ?','SKU123'  )`

Comment: @VishalJAIN That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All identifiers that are not in double-quote are converted to lower case in PG therefor your column name `Sku` get converted to `sku` so it gives this issue you can try this way:

```
UpcCode.where('"Sku" = ?','SKU123' )
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can do like

```
the_sku = 'SKU123'
UpcCode.where("Sku = ?", the_sku).first
```

---

**Update**:

```
the_sku = 'SKU123'
UpcCode.where('"Sku" = ?', the_sku).first
```

`PG` needs you to wrap case-sensitive column names with `double-quotation` marks.

The benifit of using `?` is, it portects you from `SQL Injection`

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

---

**My Suggestion**

You should follow convention of not having case-sensitive `column_names`. 
In `Rails` we follow community convention because of the following reasons

- it makes your code more predictable to future collaborators
- You will get answers in community wiki and SO more quickly and easily; You dont have to wonder for long
- `convention over configuration` is the strongest point we `Rails` community have.
- ...

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer twice. Once for the sql injection warning & once for the convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
UpcCode.where("'upc_codes'.'Sku' = 'SKU123'").first
```